# UWP XAML ToggleSwitch to set Speech Synthesis voice to either male or female

Tags: c#, binding, uwp-xaml, speech-synthesis, toggleswitch

I am trying to set the voice.gender to either male or female via a ToggleSwitch within the setting page in Template10 UWP app.

I declare the TG:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="VoiceSelection" Header="Select Voice"
                                  IsOn="{Binding VoiceChoice, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  OffContent="Male Voice" OnContent="Female Voice" />
```

That should be fine.

I then set a boolean, that will be use to select male or female later

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public static bool _voiceChoice = true;
public bool VoiceChoice
    {
        get
        {
            return _voiceChoice;
        }
        set
        {
            _voiceChoice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VoiceChoice");
        }
    }

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

For info, here is the code that later assign the voice. That works fine too.

```
...
if (_voiceChoice == true)
                {
                    VoiceInformation voiceInfo =
                      (
                        from voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
                        where voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Female
                        select voice
                      ).FirstOrDefault() ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
                    synthesizer.Voice = voiceInfo;
                    stream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
                }
                else
...
```

Problem i have is I can select the voice by manually setting the boolean _voiceChoice, but I cannot set via the ToggleSwitch.

I also realize that this solution is not very clean, and I am open to any suggestions. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot set via ToggleSwitch"? Is there an error? Is the setter of the property not being called?

Comment: Something in the code is not right, wish i knew what.. :)

Comment: If you set the breakpoint in the property setter and swith the toggle, does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: Is your DataContext set? Bindings don't work without datacontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was looking at this completely wrongly. 

Here is what is needed to make a working ToggleSwitch to switch between male/female voice in Template10. May be cleaner solutions, but this works.

In SettingsPage.xaml, add:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="VoiceSelection" Header="Select Voice"
    IsOn="{Binding UseVoiceSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"
    OffContent="Male Voice" OnContent="Female Voice" />
```

In SettingsService.cs, add:

```
public bool UseVoiceSelection
    {
        get { return _helper.Read<bool>(nameof(UseVoiceSelection), true); }
        set
        {
            _helper.Write(nameof(UseVoiceSelection), value);
        }
    }
```

In the class SettingsPartViewModel : ViewModelBase, add:

```
public bool UseVoiceSelection
    {
        get { return _settings.UseVoiceSelection; }
        set { _settings.UseVoiceSelection = value; base.RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Finally, in a separate class, set the bool value and perform the speech synthesis:

```
public class ReadSpeech
{
    public static bool _voiceChoice = true;

    // Performs synthesis
    async Task<IRandomAccessStream> SynthesizeTextToSpeechAsync(string text)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream stream = null;
        using (SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            if (temp.SettingsPartViewModel.UseVoiceSelection == true)
            {
                VoiceInformation voiceInfo =
                  (
                    from voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
                    where voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Female
                    select voice
                  ).FirstOrDefault() ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
                synthesizer.Voice = voiceInfo;
                stream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
            }
            else
            {
                VoiceInformation voiceInfo =
                  (
                    from voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
                    where voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Male
                    select voice
                  ).FirstOrDefault() ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
                synthesizer.Voice = voiceInfo;
                stream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
            }
        }
        return (stream);
    }
```